# How do you put back the command key on a Macbook Pro Retina?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I haven't found anything for the command key. They loose part is only the actual key, the white plastic thing and the steel bars are already on. I also tried taking out the steel bar and put it on the key, but no matter how I try, I can't get the key to stick. How do I put it on?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your keyboard is broken. It would help to tell us what model you have.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Macbook Pro Retina 15 Inch Early 2013.